# dispatch_async and downlaing images from cloud in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, dispatch-async

I am trying to download a few posts with images from Firebase and display them in my tableview. In the code below I notice that the tableview only gets loaded after it has downloaded every image from the preLoadImage function call. I am calling the entire loadDataFromFirebase() call in another dispatch_async call. What am I doing wrong here ? Shouldn't the preLoadImage function be running in a background queue and tableview load immediately ?

Right now I see this from the logs, so I can tell that all the 1+ MB images are being downloaded first and then the tableview is loaded. Thanks
Downlading image
Downlading image
Downlading image
Downlading image
Downlading image
Downlading image
Downlading image
Downlading image
Downlading image
Downlading image
In TableView

```
// loadDataFromFirebase is being called from another dispatch_async call
 func loadDataFromFirebase() {

        print("Global: Loading data from Firebase")
        // code to retrieve data.                

        self.globalPost.insert(userPost, atIndex: 0)
//helps imageloading -- this is the one that causes the delay 
        self.preLoadImage(userPost.userImage)
        print ("Obtained DATA in loadDataFromFirebase")


        }




// image loading - this is called in a background queue but until the download here doesn't finish my tableview does not load.

    func preLoadImage(image: String) {
        if (image != "") {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                UIImage.cachedImageWithURL(image)
                print ("Downlading image")

        })


        }

    }
```

Comment: Wondering if there is a way to limit the number of images downloaded in the background instead of downloading all the images.

Answer (score 0):

Using this in the preLoadImage() fixed it. Does this look correct ?

```
if (image != "") {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0))  {
                UIImage.cachedImageWithURL(image)
                print ("Downlading image")
            }
```